# В чем проблема удаление?

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`otzyvy.org`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_companies_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `companies` where `id` = 1954)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы хотите удалить компанию, для которой есть комментарии. В этом случае комментарии будут ссылаться на несуществующую компанию. Ограничение внешних ключей не даёт вам сделать такую операцию. Сперва удалите все комментарии, затем компанию.

Comment: Большое спасибо!